# SQL Server Database Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can any one please help me regarding that error in SQL server 
" SQL Server Database Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

```
 select * from
(select row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) rn, 
     (select distinct  test1,test2,test3
from table1
where table1.test1= 1
EXCEPT
select distinct  test1,test2,test3
from table2
where table2.test1= 1)
 ) 
  where rn between 0 and 100
```

Comment: can you give some sample data?

Comment: It's not clear what you were trying to do here. Sample data and expected results would improve this immensely (please [edit] your question to include these)

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` is useless when using `EXCEPT` as that will remove duplicates anyway.

Comment: Also: the expression: `select row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) rn` can be simplified to `1` as your query has no `from` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select * from
(select row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) rn,a.test1,a.test2,a.test3 
    from  (select distinct  test1,test2,test3
from table1
where table1.test1= 1
EXCEPT
select distinct  test1,test2,test3
from table2
where table2.test1= 1) a
 ) b
  where b.rn between 0 and 100
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply I have tried like this getting follwing error please help regarding this- "SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Answer (score 0):

There are multi errors in your query:-

First one:-

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

**Fix:** Type alias for derived table (I am gonna type `myTable` as an alias below)

---

second one:-

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'myTable'

**Fix:** Type alias for derived column (I am gonna type `myCol` as an alias below)

---

Third one:- (Thant you mentioned in your question)

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

**Reason:** You can't return two (or multiple) columns in your subquery.

The resolved Query:-

```
 select * from
(
    select 
        row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) rn, 
        (
            select distinct  test1
            from table1
            where table1.test1= 1
            EXCEPT
            select distinct  test1
            from table2
            where table2.test1= 1
        ) myCol
 ) myTable
  where rn between 0 and 100
```

*Maybe the result is not what you need, but unless this a working query and now you have the keys for handling yours as your needs.*